# How to customize FIFA 13 Chants in PC?

Tags: fifa-13

Can anyone please tell me the procedure how can I customize FIFA 13 Chants in the PC version of the game?

Answer (score 3):

Get all the chants you want, and put them in one folder.  Open them all in Windows Media Player, and save them as a playlist, but make sure that the format is m3u before you save.

You can then put the playlist in the My Music folder in `C:\Users\<your username>\`, so put the playlist you made there.

Start the game, and follow these menu options:

- Customize FIFA
- My Music and Chants
- Custom Music & Chants
- Leagues and Teams
- Choose the team you want

Then let's say you want to change the crowd chants. Select it, and then you will find the playlist that you made is there.  Choose it and choose 'Apply to Selected Event'

Comment: i couldn't make this work. any troubleshooting tips?